# Cargar un archivo JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.7

¿Cómo hago para cargar todo un archivo de JSON que está escrito en forma de diccionarios?, además es para que quede como un grafo. Las constelaciones son el "grupo" más grande, tienen el nombre, en este caso "Constelación del burro" y tiene unas estrellas, la principal y las demás que están conectadas a ella.

```
     "constellations": [
    {
      "name":"Constelación del Burro",
      "stars":[
        {
          "id": 1,
          "label": "Alpha1",
          "linkedTo": [
            {
              "starId": 2,
              "distance": 120
            },
            {
              "starId": 4,
              "distance": 87
            },
            {
              "starId": 5,
              "distance": 101
            }
          ],
          "radius": 0.4,
          "timeToEat": 3,
          "amountOfEnergy": 1,
          "coordenates": {
            "x": 25,
            "y": 34
          },
          "hypergiant": false
        }]
      ]
   ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al json citado le falta una llave antes del último corchete, luego para leer el archivo y convertirlo hacemos lo siguiente

```
import json  #1
with open("c:\miarchivo.json", 'r') as archivo:  #2
    constelaciones = json.loads("{%s}" % archivo.read())  #3
```

1. Importamos json
2. Abrimos el archivo en modo lectura
3. Envolvemos en llaves para que sea valido el json del ejemplo y lo convertimos en un diccionario.

Edito: Olvidé lo del grafo, aunque no me queda del todo claro su aspecto y cual sería su salida, podemos utilizar pydot para dicho trabajo.

```
import pydot

graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='graph')

for constelacion in constelaciones["constellations"]:
    for estrella in constelacion["stars"]:
        e_estrella = pydot.Edge(constelacion["name"], estrella["label"])
        graph.add_edge(e_estrella)
        for enlace in estrella["linkedTo"]:
            e_enlace = pydot.Edge(estrella["label"], enlace["starId"])
            graph.add_edge(e_enlace)

graph.write_png('constelaciones.png')
```

Recorremos el diccionario por cada constelación, se agrega cada estrella y por cada estrella sus enlaces, lo guardamos en un archivo en formato png.

Este es el gráfico generado para el ejemplo citado
[image: Constelación del burro]